# How to multiply two EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

okay i got this code it works perfectly with all normal numbers but when i run it and give the First or second EditText (0.1, 0.2  , 0.3 , 0.4) or any other numbers start with (0. ) it gets an error so please help me out!

```
public class Main extends Activity {

EditText num1,num2;
TextView resu;
int res;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    num1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum1);
    num2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum2);
    resu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String mynum1=num1.getText().toString();
            int mnum1=Integer.parseInt(mynum1);

            String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();
            int mnum2=Integer.parseInt(mynum2);

            res=mnum1*mnum2;
            resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `0.` values are `Float` values and you are casting into `int` so its gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your EditTextvalues to Float like:

```
  String mynum1=num1.getText().toString();
  float mnum1= Float.parseFloat(mynum1);

  String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();
  float mnum2= Float.parseFloat(mynum2);

   float res=mnum1*mnum2;
   resu.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: If your values starts from 0. then they are Float so that you need to parse your String To Float

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText num1,num2;
TextView resu;
double res;
```

in your onClickview()

```
 double mnum1=Double.parseDouble(mynum1);

        String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();
        double mnum2=Double.parseDouble(mynum2);

        res=mnum1*mnum2;
        resu.setText(Double.toString(res));
```